# Unable to Update R on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, repository, r

I [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736286/unable-to-update-r-on-linux-mint-18) posted this on the Stack Overflow site. I understand that it is inappropriate to ask the same question on multiple sites, but they were unable to help and I was told to come here.

I am unable to install the R package ggplot2 because it depends on the package digest, which requires R (>= 3.3.0) and I only have 3.2.3. I tried upgrading R as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214061/how-to-upgrade-r-in-linux), but I get an unusual message after the first line and an error after the third. The results of the first 3 lines are below exactly as the appear on the command terminal, edited for privacy and empty lines before commands added for clarity.

```
Name1@Name2 ~ $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
[sudo] password for Name1: 
Executing: /tmp/tmp.BIQ28xf0ql/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Name1@Name2 ~ $ sudo echo "deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://cran.wustl.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

Name1@Name2 ~ $ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

All commands after the third give the same errors, with commands 4 and 6 giving the errors twice for some reason.

I will be frank and admit that this whole think is very beyond me and I am just copying and pasting the code that supplied without understanding most of it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the error message says, you've a malformed line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Fix the error - or post it in your question if need be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R repository supports two different versions of R:

- 3.5 and later and
- 4.0 and later.

According to your question, you want the first one. Linux Mint 18 is based on Ubuntu Xenial, so its version should be suitable. Then, according to [the official manual](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README), you need different line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

You should be able to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with a text editor like `nano`. If using `nano`, you can open the file for editing with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Navigate to the entry with arrow keys, and correct it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, enter `y`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit editing.

Comment: I fixed sources.list like you said, but another problem came up about dependencies. Fortunately, I solved it using the package aptitude, as described here (https://www.reddit.com/r/Rsoftware/comments/fxjc45/linux_install_help/). Thank for the help.